# double labels on x and y axis in ggplot

Tags: r

I want to make a scatter plot via ggplot, where both x and y axis have double values marked ..
for example - x axis will show the labels - both after and before log transformation of the values.. and same for y axis..

Can anyone tell me how to do that?
I am able to create a secondary axis to plot the values, but I do not want that
I want both the values should be plotted in a double layer on both x and y axis:
so that the upper labels labels shows log values and the lower labels shows values before
log transformation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with `scale_*_continuous`. You can use it to do the transformation and then you can change the labels manually (using the `labels` argument).

```
library(ggplot2)

df.data <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                      y=c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000))

labels.y <- paste(round(log10(df.data$y),1), df.data$y, sep='\n')
labels.x <- paste(round(log10(df.data$x),1), df.data$x, sep='\n')

ggplot(df.data) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = df.data$y,
                     trans = 'log10',
                     labels=labels.y) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df.data$x,
                     trans = 'log10',
                     labels=labels.x) +
  xlab('log(x)\nx') + ylab('log(y)\ny') +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0),
        axis.title.x = element_text(angle=0,hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Great! It helped a lot! Thank you !